# Loss of functionality when using Chatter Desktop with Chatter External license

Tags: chatter

I'm using Chatter Desktop across a number of Orgs. In some of these I'm an external chatter user and I've only just noticed (!) that the input box used to create posts (at the top of the feed) isn't available for these Orgs.

[image]

If I log into the Org I can post, and I have the ability to comment through the desktop client so I'm quite confused.

Is this a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if you only belong to one group, you must be viewing the group feed to post in it. By default, it shows you your feed and since you can't post to your profile as an external user, you have no input box. Click on the group name in one of the posts or the groups icon and then select the group. You should then have a post box.